# How to use Django in order to present an old database without ruining it when using syncdb?

Tags: django, sqlite

I have a database in sqlite and I want to use Django to present it and make queries on it.

I know how to create a new database by creating new classes in `models.py`, but what is the best way to use Django to access an **existing** database?

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a question in two parts: firstly, how can one write django model classes to represent an existing database, and secondly how that interacts with `syncdb`.

The answer to the first of these is that django models are not expressive enough to describe every possible SQL database schema, and instead use a subset that works well with the ORM's usage pattern. Tnerefore you may need to accept some adjustments to your schema in order to describe it with django models. In particular:

- Django does not support composite primary keys. That is, you can't have a primary key that spans multiple columns.
- Django expects tables to be named `appname_modelname`, because this convention allows the tables from many apps to easily co-exist in the same database.

If your schema happens to match the subset that django models support or you are willing to make changes to adapt it to be so then your task is simply to write models that match with the schema. [The `inspectdb` tool](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/legacy-databases/) may provide a useful starting point.

You can test if you've been successful in describing your database by temporarily reconfiguring your project to use a different *empty* database and running `manage.py syncdb`, and then comparing the schema that Django created with the schema that already existed. If they are the same (or at least close enough) then you got it right.

If your existing database is *not* a good match for Django ORM's assumptions then a more flexible alternative is [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/). It doesn't natively integrate into django's application system but it does provide a more complete database interface that can work with almost any database; some databases will be easy to map, and some others will require some more manual mapping work, but almost all cases should be possible with some creativity.

As for the interaction with `syncdb`: the default behavior for this command is to skip over any models that already seem to have tables in the database. Therefore if you've defined models that do indeed match with your existing database tables it should leave them alone. It *will*, however, create the additional tables required for other apps in your project, including Django's own tables.

Modern Django has [support for multiple databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/), which could provide you with a further approach: configure your existing database as a *second* database source in your project and use a *database router* to ensure that the appropriate models are loaded from that second database, and further to ensure that django won't attempt to run `syncdb` on this database. This provides true separation at the expense of some additional complexity, but it still requires that your schema be compatible with the ORM's assumptions. It also has [some limitations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#limitations-of-multiple-databases), largely pertaining to relationships between objects that are persisted in different databases.

If you'd like to be able to make versioned changes to the database Django uses, starting with the schema you've inherited from the existing database, then [South](http://south.aeracode.org/) provides a more flexible and more complete alternative to the builtin `syncdb` mechanism that supports running arbitrary SQL data definition language statements to make changes to your database schema.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need something like [South](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/0.7.6/) which will allow you to version and and revert changes to your models.

Answer (score 1):

You just need [`./manage.py inspectdb`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/legacy-databases/).

Comment: "just" isn't the *mot juste* here.

Comment: So basically what I need to do is the following:
1. build in modles the class suitable to the db
2. call inspectdb

Comment: No. Calling inspectdb builds the models for you.